# $_GET and paginate_links() in WordPress persist in returning me to 1

Tags: php, wordpress, get

I am trying to develop a user directory using paginate_links() in WordPress.  The following appears to set up correctly with the URLs for the page links built correctly (for example link 3 gives me https://www.example.com/private-messaging/?pmaction=directory&p=3).  However, $_GET['p'] is not capturing the page number.  When I check it with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] I get pmaction=directory.  When I check it with print_r($_GET) I am returned 1 regardless of the url.  When I extract key and value from $_GET the following are returned: Key = pmaction, Value= directory. I am not sure what I am missing. $_GET works fine elsewhere in the application using similar a method but not here. What may I be doing wrong?

If I manually send this url in my browser: 
https://www.example.com/private-messaging/?pmaction=directory&p=3

It strips off the end and displays only this:
https://www.example.com/private-messaging/?pmaction=directory

And I am at step 1 of the process.  If I manually set $page = 3; I will see step three (and only step 3).

```
function dispDirectory()
{
  global $user_ID;

  // Disallow directory if there is a messaging administrator and this person is not it.
  if ($this->admin_user_id && $this->admin_user_id != $user_ID) {
    return '';
  }

    $count_args  = array(
        'role'      => 'Client',
        'fields'    => 'all_with_meta',
        'number'    => 999999      
    );
    $user_count_query = new WP_User_Query($count_args);
    $user_count = $user_count_query->get_results();
    $total_users = $user_count ? count($user_count) : 1;
    $page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 1;
    $users_per_page = 15;
    $total_pages = 1;
    $offset = $users_per_page * ($page - 1);
    $total_pages = ceil($total_users / $users_per_page);

    $directory = "<form name='form' method='post'><label for='clientname'>Client Name: </label>
    <input name='clientname' id='clientname' type='text' style='width: 181px;'
    value=''/><input type='submit'></form>";

    $search_string = $_POST["clientname"];

    if (!empty($search_string)) {
    $args  =  array ( 
            'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'first_name',
                'value'   => $search_string,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'last_name',
                'value'   => $search_string,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
            )
        );
    }else{
    $args  =  array (   
        'meta_key' => 'last_name',
        // return all fields
        'fields'    => 'all_with_meta',
        'number'    => $users_per_page,
        'offset'    => $offset // skip the number of users that we have per page            
        );  
    }

    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
    $wp_user_query->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', 'wp_usermeta.meta_value', $wp_user_query->query_orderby );
    $wp_user_query->query();

    $users = $wp_user_query->get_results();

    if (!empty($users)) {

      foreach($users as $u)
      {
        $firstName = get_user_meta($u->ID, 'first_name', true);
        $lastName = get_user_meta($u->ID, 'last_name', true);         

        $directory .= '<p><strong>'.$lastName.', '.$firstName.'</strong> - <a href="'.$this->actionURL.'newmessage&to='.$u->ID.'">'.__('Send Message', 'cartpaujpm').'</a>  <a href="'.$this->actionURL.'oldmessages&to='.$u->ID.'">'.__('Old Messages', 'cartpaujpm').'</a></p>';
      }
    } else {
        $directory .= '<p><strong>No Clients Found</strong></p>';
    }

    $directory .= paginate_links( array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%', // the base URL, including query arg
        'format' => '&p=%#%', // this defines the query parameter that will be used, in this case "p"
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'), // text for previous page
        'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'), // text for next page
        'total' => $total_pages, // the total number of pages we have
        'current' => $page, // the current page
        'end_size' => 1,
        'mid_size' => 5,
    ));
    return $directory;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying this?

```
        function dispDirectory()
        {
              global $user_ID;

              // Disallow directory if there is a messaging administrator and this person is not it.
             if ($this->admin_user_id && $this->admin_user_id != $user_ID) {
                return '';
              }

                $count_args  = array(
                  //  'role'      => 'Client',
                    'fields'    => 'all_with_meta',
                    'number'    => 999999      
                );
                $user_count_query = new WP_User_Query($count_args );

                $user_count = $user_count_query->get_results();
                $total_users = $user_count ? count($user_count) : 1;
                $page = isset($_GET['pagenum']) ? $_GET['pagenum'] : 1;
                $limit = 2;
                $offset = $limit * ($page - 1);
                $total_pages = ceil($total_users / $limit);

                $directory .= "<form name='form' method='post'><label for='clientname'>Client Name: </label>
                <input name='clientname' id='clientname' type='text' style='width: 181px;'
                value=''/><input type='submit'></form>";

                $search_string = $_POST["clientname"];

                if (!empty($search_string)) {
                $args  =  array ( 
                        'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'first_name',
                            'value'   => $search_string,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'last_name',
                            'value'   => $search_string,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        )
                        )
                    );
                }else{
                $args  =  array (   
                    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
                    // return all fields
                    'fields'    => 'all_with_meta',
                    'number'    => $limit,
                    'offset'    => $offset // skip the number of users that we have per page            
                    );  
                }

                $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
                $wp_user_query->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', 'wp_usermeta.meta_value', $wp_user_query->query_orderby );
                $wp_user_query->query();

                $users = $wp_user_query->get_results();


                if (!empty($users)) {

                  foreach($users as $u)
                  {
                    $firstName = get_user_meta($u->ID, 'first_name', true);
                    $lastName = get_user_meta($u->ID, 'last_name', true);         

                   $directory .= '<p><strong>'.$lastName.', '.$firstName.'</strong> - <a href="newmessage&to='.$u->ID.'">'.__('Send Message', 'cartpaujpm').'</a>  <a href="oldmessages&to='.$u->ID.'">'.__('Old Messages', 'cartpaujpm').'</a></p>';
                  }
                } else {
                    $directory .= '<p><strong>No Clients Found</strong></p>';
                }


                echo  $directory;

                /*$directory = paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%', // the base URL, including query arg
                    'format' => '&p=%#%', // this defines the query parameter that will be used, in this case "p"
                    'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'), // text for previous page
                    'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'), // text for next page
                    'total' => $total_pages, // the total number of pages we have
                    'current' => $page, // the current page
                    'end_size' => 1,
                    'mid_size' => 5,
                ));*/


                    $page_links = paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
                        'format' => '',
                        'prev_text' => __( '&laquo;', 'text-domain' ),
                        'next_text' => __( '&raquo;', 'text-domain' ),
                        'total' => $total_pages,
                        'current' => $page
                    ) );

                    if ( $page_links ) {
                        echo '<div class="tablenav" style="width: 99%;"><div class="tablenav-pages" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</div></div>';
                    }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, what I took from your example was changing the reference from 'p' to 'pagenum' and then changing the 'base' property to add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' )  with 'format' 'blank.  That worked.  I like the CSS options but I am keeping this rather basic.  Thank you very much.  It is running great.